# Eigen3: Cast Dynamic Matrix to Static Matrix

Tags: c++, eigen, eigen3

is possible to cast a dynamic matrix to a static one and if yes what woud be the best solution?
Example:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd a = Eigen::Matrixxd::Zero(4,4);
```

to

```
Eigen::Matrix<double, a.rows(), a.cols()> b = a; //?
```

Cheers!

Comment: what do you get? does it compile? does it error in run-time? But I doubt it, the template parameters must be know at compile time, it doesn't seems likely to be the case here.

Comment: I get an compile error due to the not static initialization of b. I can not define a matrix by a.rows() because it is not at compile time. I search a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialMatrixClass.html).

> The three mandatory template parameters of Matrix are:
> Matrix<typename Scalar, int RowsAtCompileTime, int ColsAtCompileTime>.
>
> RowsAtCompileTime and ColsAtCompileTime are the number of rows and columns of the > matrix as known at compile time

When you use `Eigen::MatrixXd`,

> The RowsAtCompileTime and ColsAtCompileTime template parameters can take the special value Dynamic which indicates that the size is **unknown at compile time**,  so must be handled as a run-time variable

Given that size of `a` is unknown at compile time, you cannot get value of `a.rows()`.

Given that you know size of `a` at compile time, you should use `Eigen::Matrix` and not `Eigen::MatrixXd`. However, if you don't know `a.rows()` or `a.cols()`, you have to declare `b` as `Eigen::MatrixXd`. You cannot use `Eigen::Matrix`